# Making a FormBody Shrink and Expand Using JQuery and SharePoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sharepoint

I am creating a form in sharepoint. I have an ms-FormBody for a text box. I would like for the user to be able to double click the box in order to expand the box and if they double click again, it will shrink back up. Again this is in SharePoint.

EDIT: Thanks to some help from @Thriggle I am very close to the goal I wanted with this project. The problem now is that Whatever you type will only stay on one line (t ext wrapping maybe?). Also The text box doesn't actually take up less space (This is not a big deal but if you can think of anyway to make the rest of the boxes move as this box resizes) and I was wondering if there is a way that the box will be small when program launches.

[image: Image of big text boxes]
[image: Image of small text boxes]
[image: Problem with project]

Comment: what is issue you are facing with above jsfiddle code ......... replace click with "dblclick"

Comment: I tried that and while it worked in the fiddle, none of this actually works on my Nintex form.

Comment: Does the text wrap if it has a space in it?

Comment: I guess that isn't really a big deal. Nobody would ever type a word that long anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screenshots, I'm assuming that you're using Nintex Forms.

**For Plain Text Multi-Line Fields**

The following will work for plain text multiline fields, but not for rich text or enhanced rich text fields (neither of which are represented by an ordinary textarea element).

In your form settings, in the Custom JavaScript section, you can add the following code:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){setTimeout(checkFieldExists,1000);},"sp.js");

function checkFieldExists(){
    // Nintex forms load slowly; we'll hold off on running the code
    // until we're able to access the element through the DOM.
    var field = document.getElementById(DescriptionID);
    if(field){
        // The field exists, time to attach an event listener.
        addExpansionToggleEvent(field);
    }else{
        // Wait a second, then check again.
        setTimeout(checkFieldExists,1000);
    }
}

function addExpansionToggleEvent(field){
    field.style.height = ""; // remove the default height=100%
    field.ondblclick = function(){
        var rows = field.getAttribute("rows"); 
        field.setAttribute("rows",+rows < 10 ? 10 : 1);
    };
}
```

This is assuming you added a client ID of `DescriptionID` to the plain text multiline field that you want to toggle, as shown in your screenshot.

**For Rich Text Multi-Line Fields**

Rich text fields are (bizarrely) represented by iframes instead of `textarea` elements.

The following code can be added to your Custom JavaScript section to provide expand/shrink behavior upon double-clicking a rich text field, but note that this does not readjust the way other controls are laid out on the form to account for the field's new size... so it's not especially useful.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){setTimeout(checkFieldExists,1000);},"sp.js");
function checkFieldExists(){
    var iframes = document.querySelectorAll("iframe[title=\"Rich Text Editor\"]");
    if(iframes.length > 0){
        addExpansionToggleEvent(iframes);
    }else{
        setTimeout(checkFieldExists,1000);
    }
}
function addExpansionToggleEvent(iframes){
    for(var i = 0, len = iframes.length; i < len; i++){
        var body = iframes[i].contentDocument.querySelector("body");
        (function(container){
            body.ondblclick = function(){
                container.height = +(container.height) < 140 ? 140 : 30; 
            };
        })(iframes[i]);
    }
}
```

Again, this code is specifically targeted toward rich text field, and will not work for plain text or enhanced rich text fields.

Comment: Well I tried what you gave and it didn't quite work. I'm thinking it might be a rich text field or something, but I know it is not a plain text box. Will post a picture for what it looks like.

Comment: @MattCucco Can you switch the SharePoint column from rich text to plain text, or does the customer absolutely require rich text?

Comment: They would require the rich text. I was told if I can't get it to work this way then not to worry about it. Is there any way that you know of to just get the box to be able to expand upon a double click?

Comment: Hi @MattCucco, I've updated my answer with some code that targets rich text fields.

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to put the DescriptionID anywhere in there?

Comment: Nope, that code indiscriminately applies the double click event listener to all rich text fields that it can find.

Comment: So that worked really close to what I wanted it to do! Thanks for That! Now i have a new problem the text. Is there a way to make it wrap? I will update my question with more information

Comment: It should try to wrap words when it can, but it won't split words in half.